# Equivalent of Rectangle (JAVA) in Android

Tags: java, android, rect

I need the clone method for Rectangle in Android.

Android has Rect instead of Rectangle. But it doesn' t have `clone()` method.

Is there any method equivalent with `clone()`

Comment: rect has predefined methods..!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Rect` has a copy constructor [`Rect(Rect)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#Rect(android.graphics.Rect)) that you can use for cloning:

```
Rect duplicatedRect = new Rect(originalRect);
```